# java how to extract json element for many depth levels

Tags: java, android, json, apache

if i have this json

```
{
"aggregations" : {
"cityAgg": {
"'buckets": {
"buckets" : [
{},{},{}
]
}
}
}
}
```

I can extract the last `buckets` array like this using **simple json**

```
JSONObject aggregations = (JSONObject)jsonResponse.get("aggregations");
        JSONObject cityAgg = (JSONObject)aggregations.get("cityAgg");
        JSONObject buckets = (JSONObject) cityAgg.get("buckets");
        JSONArray result = (JSONArray) buckets.get("buckets");
```

but it is boring to make object for each json level, isn't there a better/easier way to do that?

something maybe like:

```
jsonResponse.get("aggregation/cityAgg/buckets/buckets")
```

Comment: use retrofit 2 netwoking  library it automatically parses the json for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) provided by Google to format json,convert Object to Json and vice versa.

Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

Can go through samples here : 
[Gson Usage](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

**Example**

{

```
"aggregations" : {
"cityAgg": {
"'buckets": {
"buckets" : [
{},{},{}
]
}
}
}
}
```

Create a model which has such depth hierarchy

```
class Aggregations{
  private CityAgg cityAgg;
  //getters and setters
}

class CityAgg{
 private Bucket buckets;
 //getters and setters
}

class Bucket{
  //some properties
}
```

you'll use the parent class to get all properties loaded inside it

Comment: okay i've added it, but still how can i make multi level selection please ?

Comment: Okay i see your updated code, but please how can i bind the string to the model classes you've created ?

Comment: plus, is it correct, that you created Bucket as one object, while it is an array in the json